# Accumulo not sourcing accumulo-site.xml during initialization

Tags: hadoop, apache-zookeeper, accumulo

I'm facing an issue with Apache Accumulo where it seems to be not sourcing the `accumulo-site.xml` file during initialization. I have made sure that the `accumulo-site.xml` file exists in the correct location (`conf/` directory) of my Accumulo installation. However, when I run the `accumulo init` command, it does not report any errors related to the `accumulo-site.xml` file. i still  get the following error message:ZOOKEEPER_HOME is not set or is not a directory. Please make sure it's set globally or in `conf/accumulo-env.sh`.

I have tried intentionally introducing errors in the `accumulo-site.xml` file to check if Accumulo detects them, but it does not provide any error messages. This suggests that Accumulo might not be reading the `accumulo-site.xml` file at all. that's why he give me error about not locating the ZOOKEEPER_HOME

Here are a few details of my setup:

Accumulo version: [1.10.3]
ZooKeeper version: [3.4.6]

> Note: iam using separate ZooKeeper cluster

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accumulo error: "ZOOKEEPER\_HOME is not set or is not a directory" with separate ZooKeeper cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76239734/accumulo-error-zookeeper-home-is-not-set-or-is-not-a-directory-with-separate)

Comment: You asked the same question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76239734, and I already answered it there. Please don't ask the same question multiple times.

Comment: @Christopher  it’s not the same question, I have 2 problems first that accumulo does not source accumulo-site.xml and second does not locate zookeeper.  thank you for your answer but it didn’t help

Comment: The question is the same because the error message you're describing is the same. The only thing different is your speculation about the cause. Over there, you speculated that it couldn't find ZooKeeper from the configuration you set in the accumulo-site.xml file. Here, you're speculating that it's not reading the accumulo-site.xml at all. Neither is the true cause of the problem. The answer relates to accumulo-env.sh and not accumulo-site.xml, as explained in the other question.